# onPlayFromSearch not called

Tags: android, android-tv

I want to enable voice commands.

When i say 'play next station' -> ok onSkipToNext(...) is called

When i say 'play previous station' -> ok onSkipToPrevious(...) is called

When i say 'play blubber' (something undefined) -> ok onPlayFromSearch(...) is called

When i say 'play NDR 2' (a really existing radio station) -> nothing called in my app, but google say 'therefore you need to install tunein ....'

tuneis is a competitor to us.... what is going on?

We are located in germany, if its important to the question.

I have no idea what todo... i would expect onPlayFromSearch will be called everytime i say something like 'play ...'